# java - Spring Boot JPA - Wrong JOIN by JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, many-to-one

I'm trying to create an association between two tables such as :
Representation can have multiple Bookings,
Booking can only have a single Representation

I was trying to use the Javax persistence @ManyToOne from my Booking.java entity.

However when i'm trying to reach the view of my bookings, I have an error return :

`java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'representation.booking' in 'on clause'`

This error makes sens to me, but i don't uderstand why it tries to call the column representation.booking (which does not exists) in the first place.

Here's what I tried :

My Booking Entitty :

```java
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor(force = true)
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Booking{

        @Id
        @javax.persistence.Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
        Integer id;

        @NotEmpty
        @NotBlank
        String name;

        @NotNull
        @DecimalMin("1")
        Integer number;


        @NotEmpty
        @NotBlank
        @Column(value = "phoneNumber")
        String phoneNumber;

        @NotEmpty
        @Email
        String email;

        @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Representation.class)
        @JoinColumn(name = "fk_representation")
        Representation representation;
```

My Representation entity :

```java
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Representation {

        @Id
        @javax.persistence.Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
        Integer id;

        String place;

        String location;

        Integer price;

        String datetime;
```

My Controller :

```java
           @GetMapping("/view")
    public String findAllView(Model model) {
        List<Booking> bookings = repository.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("bookings", bookings);
        return "bookings";
    }
```

My Booking View :

```html
<table id="datatablesSimple">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Id</th>
                                <th>Nom</th>
                                <th>Email</th>
                                <th>Numéro de téléphone</th>
                                <th>Nombre</th>
                                <th>Evènement</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Id</th>
                                <th>Nom</th>
                                <th>Email</th>
                                <th>Numéro de téléphone</th>
                                <th>Nombre</th>
                                <th>Evènement</th>
                            </tr>
                            </tfoot>
                            <tbody>
                            <tr th:each="booking : ${bookings}">
                                <td th:utext="${booking.id}"></td>
                                <td th:utext="${booking.name}"></td>
                                <td th:utext="${booking.email}"></td>
                                <td th:utext="${booking.phoneNumber}"></td>
                                <td th:utext="${booking.number}"></td>
                                <td th:utext="${booking.representation.id}"></td>
<!--                                <td th:utext="${ticket.qrCodeSha}"></td>-->
                                <td><a  th:href="@{/admin/booking/delete/{id}(id=${booking.id})}">Delete</a></td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

My Database Structure :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS booking (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    number INTEGER NOT NULL,
    phoneNumber VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    fk_representation INTEGER NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ticket (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    boo_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    qrCodeSha VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
    );

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS representation (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    place VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    location VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    price INTEGER NOT NULL,
    datetime VARCHAR(255)
    );
```

**
The query JPA tries :**

```
SELECT `booking`.`id` AS `id`, `booking`.`name` AS `name`, `booking`.`email` AS `email`, `booking`.`number` AS `number`, `booking`.`phoneNumber` AS `phoneNumber`, `representation`.`id` AS `representation_id`, `representation`.`price` AS `representation_price`, `representation`.`place` AS `representation_place`, `representation`.`location` AS `representation_location`, `representation`.`datetime` AS `representation_datetime` FROM `booking` LEFT OUTER JOIN `representation` `representation` ON `representation`.`booking` = `booking`.`id`
```

of course it returns :
#1054 - Field 'representation.booking' unknown in on clause

**The query i'd like it to send :**

```
SELECT `booking`.`id` AS `id`, `booking`.`name` AS `name`, `booking`.`email` AS `email`, `booking`.`number` AS `number`, `booking`.`phoneNumber` AS `phoneNumber`, `representation`.`id` AS `representation_id`, `representation`.`price` AS `representation_price`, `representation`.`place` AS `representation_place`, `representation`.`location` AS `representation_location`, `representation`.`datetime` AS `representation_datetime` FROM `booking` LEFT OUTER JOIN `representation` `representation` ON `representation`.`id` = `booking`.`fk_representation`;
```

Its result :
[Screenshot of answer of expected query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EAxd.png)

Could you please help me understand what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Where is your `Event` table?
also `EVENT` is a reserved keyword, try avoiding that

Comment: Thanks for your answer !
I forgot to add the event table in my snippets, i'm adding it
I'm also retrying changing the reserved name of Event

Comment: Hi, i change my event table as "representation" table and issue stays the same.
I'll update my post with the new table name

Comment: Is your code even working?
`@Id` and `@javax.persistence.Id` in the same place? Is it even allowed?

Comment: My crud was working before trying to put a foreign key in one of my tables.

If I try to delete the @Id annotation (from import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id), i cannot for instance delete an entry and got thjis error
 : 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required identifier property not found for class com.remyscreve.starmaniaticketing.model.Representation


If I try to delete the Id from javax persistence, it doesn't compile

Comment: I tried your model and the code. Obviously there were errors like `@Column(value = "phoneNumber")`. I did not find the issue you are mentioning.

Comment: @Asgar do you mean it worked on your side with my snippets ?

Comment: I meant it did not throw the `unknown column` issue.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your help, I really don't understand what goes wrong in my side :/ ...